# How to translate this extension method to an interface method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

Let's say I have the following extension method:

```
public static TContext Timeout<TContext>(this TContext context, TimeSpan timeout)
    where TContext : IContext
{
    // ...
}
```

This extension method allows me to achieve immutability and preserve the calling type:

```
ITransactionalContext c = // ...;
c = c.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

However, how can I achieve this with an interface?

For instance, this won't be the same:

```
public interface IContext
{
    IContext Timeout(TimeSpan timeout);
}
```

Because my code example won't compile.

```
ITransactionalContext c = // ...;
c = c.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); // <-- An IContext is returned. Cannot assign to variable.
```

I can specify the context type to the interface as a generic argument:

```
public interface IContext
{

}

public interface IContext<TContext> : IContext
   where TContext : IContext
{
    TContext Timeout(TimeSpan timeout);
}

public interface ITransactionalContext : IContext<ITransactionalContext>
{

}
```

But that doesn't seem nice at all.

Also, what if `ITransactionalContext` requires more arguments:

```
public interface ITransactionalContext<TTransaction, TEntity>
    : IContext<ITransactionalContext<TTransaction, TEntity>>
{
}
```

That is some generics mess.

Is there a cleaner way to achieve what the extension method achieves?

Comment: Is "immutality" a typo for "immutability", or "immortality"? If it's the latter, *please provide complete implementation details immediately*, thank you.

Comment: `Is there a cleaner way to achieve what the extension method achieves?`  Yeah, use the extension method.  You already have a solution that does exactly what you need it to do, why are you looking for another solution?

Comment: Adding to what @Servy said, you solution looks good and although an extension method, it is using generics. Using generics in this way is an alternative to using the interface with inheritance. You say your code example will not be the same, however if you had the derived classes you would get the appropriate polymorphic behavior.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can declare the method in the interface exactly as you've done it for the extension method: `TContext Timeout<TContext>(DateTime timeout) where TContext : IContext;`. If all you want to do is move the extension method into the interface, why don't you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution with an extension method is ideal, because it relies on compiler's ability to infer `TContext`. Its major shortcoming, however, is that it does not `IContext` classes provide their own implementations of `Timeout(TimeSpan)` method. Effectively, the control of the cloning process is taken out of `IContext` implementations.

If you want to keep the control of cloning in `IContext` implementations, make a combination of an interface method and an extension method, like this:

```
interface IContext {
    ... // Your methods
    IContext CloneWithTimeout(TimeSpan timeout);
}
...
public static TContext Timeout<TContext>(this TContext context, TimeSpan timeout)
    where TContext : IContext
{
    return (TContext)context.CloneWithTimeout(timeout);
}
```

Your use case continues to compile, while the process of producing a new instance is controlled entirely by implementations of `IContext`.